# Changing extended Vue component's data upon instantiation

Tags: typescript, vue.js

If I have a base component (named `Block`), which looks similar to this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';


export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      data: "hello",
      comment: null
    }
  }

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
</template>
```

And I have another component that extends it (named `ToggleBlock`), looking like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Block from './Block.vue';


export default defineComponent({
    extends: Block,
    data() {
        return {
            toggled: false,
        }
    }
}
)

</script>
        
<template>
   
    <div>
    <span>
        <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
        <input  type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="toggled"
    </span>
    </div>



</template>
```

Suppose I have a valid JSON array with `blocks_data.new_data`=`"Hello World"`.How would I change `Block`'s `data` upon instantiating `ToggleBlock` in some other template?
I am very new to Vue, and this is what I've been trying:

`<ToggleBlock :data=blocks_data.new_data></ToggleBlock>`

This does not change data's initial value.  In order to take JSON out of the equation, I've tried:

`<ToggleBlock data=Hello World></ToggleBlock>`

But that doesn't seem to work either.  I know modifying an extended component's data is likely very simple, but I cannot seem to find what fits my case.  Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: `data` is `data` property, while you're trying to provide it as a prop. If you need it to use as a prop then define it as a prop. Otherwise write it in data(). Also you shouldn't give props and data the same names, this is ambiguous

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense.  I think I just don't understand how to set the ```data``` dynamically once I read in my JSON file and instantiate one of the components that extend ```Block```